# set a global variable in codeigniter function

Tags: codeigniter, global-variables

I have a codeigniter web application which has two buttons guest or user.  The whole application uses the same pages whether you are a guest or user, but if you click the user button I want it to bring the user to a login page, I can do that, but I need to be able to set a global variable, only if the user uses the user/login button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would set some sort of session data when processing the form submission for the user login.  Something like:

```
$this->session->set_userdata(array('is_user' => TRUE));
```

That is as close as you'll get to setting *global* data.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question similar to this one? [Access Codeigniter data variables in function inside a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983907/access-codeigniter-data-variables-in-function-inside-a-view)

In the strict sense of `global`, CodeIgniter doesn't allow user-defined globals to prevent it's own framework variables to be overwritten by the user. 
 I tried several things within the view, passing variables from controller to view, but it's never assigned to `$GLOBALS`.

You can use session or cookies to store your data if you really need to.